# update popup new window to popup without link and with background grey

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, popup

i need help to update my page. ok .. the code bellow works for me but is open a new page on that size

```
<form action="foo.php" method="post" target="POPUPW"
    onsubmit="POPUPW = window.open('about:blank','POPUPW',
   'width=600,height=400');">
...
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit in Popup">
</form>
```

what i want to do is to make something like this [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0IBk.png)

to be with grey in background and if it is posibile when i try to click on grey ,to not close the popup.
and i cant add on the page what is contain on the foo.php to make something simple.. because foo.php have redirect to something else..

just i want update what i have now with background grey and if the new open tab is with the link is not apear will be nice.

sorry for bad english.. and also im not so good on coding.

Comment: This is called a "modal window". If you research that phrase, you should find plenty of tutorials that show how to achieve it.

Comment: nop sir.. nothing good.. but ty to give me a more specific function